# gulp: inline @imports from http source and replace references

Tags: css, import, gulp

Is there a gulp.js plugin that could transform this:

```
/** main.css **/

@import url(http://example.com/theme.css);

/** http://example.com/theme.css **/

body {background: url(images/backdrop.jpg)}
```

Into:

```
/** main.css **/

body {background: url(http://example.com/images/backdrop.jpg)}
```